# Download C drive filename to a specific folder

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

On the screenshot above, I pulled in C: drive filename from a folder, Now I want to copy them and move it to a specific folder. Can anyone tell me how this can be done?

Comment: Those are not hyperlink. The are just filenames with their path. Now, do you want to copy your "hyperlinks" or di you want to copy the files?

Comment: Use the CopyFile method to copy files.

Comment: Thanks for that. will look into CopyFile Method

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Sub test()
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Set rng = Range("B2:B4") ' Replace with the range of your source file links
    For Each cell In rng
        fso.MoveFile Source:=cell.Value, Destination:="C:\dev\test\a\"  ' replace with destination folder as required.
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: I really cant stand late binding.